# change background appBar and how to style

Tags: flutter

I just want to remove the elevation, move the title in the middle and change the color

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      "Deskripsi",
      style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
        fontWeight: semiBold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

`centreTile` for placing text in middle.

`elevation` property for dropshadow

`backgroundColor` for app bar color

```
appBar: AppBar(
backgroundColor: backgroudColor,
elevation: 0,
centerTitle: true,
    title: Text(
      "Deskripsi",
      style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
        fontWeight: semiBold,
      ),
    ),
   ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. refer `AppBar` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

```
appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,//change color on your need 
    elevation: 0,
    title: Text(
      "Deskripsi",
    ),
  ),
```

Your result Screen-> [image]